# read-only input while page load

Tags: jquery, html

How to make `<input type="text" name="mynumber" value="456" />` read-only while my page is loading?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Disable it using `disabled="true"`

```
document.getElementById("t1").disabled=true

<input type="text" name="mynumber" id="t1" value="456" disabled="true"/>
```

Comment: -1 have you even tested this? and what element has the id "t1"?

Comment: I assumed "t1" to be the ID of the textbox.

Answer (score 7):

```
<input type="text" name="mynumber" value="456" readonly="readonly" />

<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("input[name='mynumber']").attr("readonly", false);
});
</script>
```

Comment: OT: I see someone removed the quotes around 'document' for me - what difference does it make (not complaining - just interested)? [edit] Ha !

Comment: @Grim... you can also write just 
$(function(){ /* ... */ });

Comment: document is the document object in browsers, in quotes you are trying to select <document> element which does not exist :)

Comment: Note that visitors without javascript won't be able to input something.

Comment: wouldn't it be better to use the readonly attribute rather than disabled... doesn't disabled stop it from being included in submission?

Comment: @ianbarker - Yes, yes it would.

Comment: @ianbarker the js is removing the disabled, so it would be included.

Comment: Still, read-only is a better answer to the question as asked.

Comment: @Grim... i didn't think it would work - so apparently yes! :)